# Feature selection: ANOVA between features vs within a feature

Tags: machine-learning, regression, feature-selection, anova

I am currently performing feature selection on a dataset containing continuous and categorical features. The target is a continuous variable.

If I understand properly, ANOVA can be used *between* features, but can it also be used *within* a feature? For example, I have a feature called 'blood types', which contains categorical data such as 'A+', 'B-', ... Can I use an ANOVA test to check whether the variation of the target variable is statistically significant between each of the categories? And if so, can I remove the feature if this variation is not significant (= knowing the category doesn't tell us much about the target variable, therefore this feature doesn't bring statistically useful information)?

Thank you.